# NFS mount best practice

Tags: server, mount, nfs, symbolic-link

Say I have some data on an NFS server that is currently mounted to `/mnt/data` on a client but I want to have it accessible at `/home/user/data` instead, both server and client are running 22.04.

Would it be best practice to mount the NFS data share directly to `/home/user/data` or use some kind of symlink or hard link to point `/home/user/data` to `/mnt/data`?

Or does it really not matter? My gut feeling is to just mount the NFS share directly to the desired location.

Comment: Is `/home/user` mounted via NFS?

Comment: no it's not, `/mnt/data` is the only NFS mount

Comment: Will `/home/user/data` be the only place where `data` should be used, or are there more places (in future) ? e.g. `/home/user2/data` ?

Comment: `/home/user/data` will be the only place `data` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on some things.

Parent folder is NFS mount: In this case I would use a symlink, because in worst case the mount-in-mount might freeze your whole system (network down, nfs-server restart, ...)

Need it at several places: I think multiple mounts of the same NFS directory in worst case could lead to data loss (locking). Better use symlink to the single mount.

Access Permissions: Be aware, that Linux is a multiuser System (many user can be logged in, e.g. from remote via ssh, xdmcp, ...). Depending on the security needs mounting it "somewhere" and using symlink might give others access without being aware of.

As the question asking for an "opinion", not for a "solution", this is my personal opinion from my experience. Others might see this different.